# What is the best way to publish multiple versions of the same ClickOnce application?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, clickonce

I have a c# ClickOnce application that I need to be able to publish multiple times for OEM purposes.

The way I understand it now is that publish settings are located in the .csproj file.
However, this is inconvenient in the case where I want to publish multiple versions.

for example, Company A needs totally different icons, start menu location, product name etc. from Company B, but the assemblies need not be renamed.

Here are a couple approaches/questions that I can think of to solve this issue...

> 1.Is there a way to create a separate publish settings file to use during build time?
>
> 2.Can I edit specific publish settings (like Start Menu location, etc) at build time with MSBuild.exe? I think this would be ideal...
>   e.g.
>
> > MSBuild.exe project.sln /target:Publish /property:**edit-project-publish-settings-here**
>
> 3.Maybe create a 2nd .csproj file? (Would prefer not to do this...)

Please share your thoughts as to the best approach, or any other clever ways to make this happen. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copy the .csproj in your project folder, it will reference all of the same source files and you can just change the executable name. Create another VS solution and you can reference the copied .csproj and get rid of your first one so that you can publish two separate versions.

This isn't ideal for ClickOnce however.

If you use a Singleton object that specifies the "mode" (Company A, B, C, etc.) you can easily store that in the app.config (or another xml file). Then just re-publish your ClickOnce Application but copy the correct version of your configuration file in so it gets shipped with the build. *This way, you don't need any additional csprojects* Just include all of your icons and set them at run-time on App Start based on your Singleton object.

Answer (score 2):

I wish I could give you some brilliant solution, but personally I would probably go with option 3.

I mean, its pretty simple, the changes should be pretty static and it will be difficult(ish) to totally screw it up and deploy the wrong changes to the wrong company.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you are able to edit certain properties using MSBuild.exe like this

> MSBuild Solution.sln /target:publish /property:**ProductName**=ProductA\;**Publisher**=CompanyA\;**ApplicationIcon**=companyA.ico

I found another useful post on [modifying.csproj files programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887538/modify-programatically-csproj-files) with .NET code. *(This would only be needed if you're modifying things that are deeper than just the project properties specified in the ClickOnce documentation below)*

The [MSBuild documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) here was also useful -- especially under **Publishing Properties**