# How to change icon ( of main Form + another child forms) programatically in c# code while compilation

Tags: c#, ico

I am struggling with how to change the main program icon during compilation.
I know it can be changed in Visual Studio Project-> Properties -> Application -> and there is button Change icon.

Okay, how can I do exactly the same now without manually setting this icon? I just want to change it via the c# code. Is it possible at all?
Screen settings looks like this:
[image]

I tried this code in form load event , but it only changes icon after I start my application.

```
System.Drawing.Icon ico = new System.Drawing.Icon(FastFoodDemo.Properties.Resources.red_mark);
this.Icon = ico;
```

The question is : How can I change the application main icon during compilation without do it by hand like on the above screenshoot. Please don't make this post as duplicate, I searched a lot of webpages and couldn't find any solution in c#.

Comment: _"Please don't make this post as duplicate"_ - so if somebody had asked this exact question and received a perfectly adequate answer that also answers your question, you wouldn't want your question to be marked as a duplicate on principle? That seems weird. Anyway, why are you trying to do this? What is the end goal? Why is that better than manually editing this? Either way, I don't think you should expect to do this within your application code, since that isn't _executed_ during compilation. It should be part of your build process.

Comment: `this.Icon = ico;` changes the _form icon_. As you seem to be aware, the executable icon is separate.

Comment: Yeah i know it , so  I write need to have the same result as changing by this button.

Comment: Which problem you are trying to solve by changing icon "while compilation"? Why you can't use shown dialog?

Comment: Please answer the questions I asked. It's not really clear _why_ you are trying to do this. If you answered them, it would give everyone a better idea of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: For example i need to compile 10 x my application with different exe icon. And need to load this icon while compilation without change it by this button after each build

Comment: [What about a flag to MSBuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17792708/3181933)

Comment: It's not clear how you run 10x compilations. I can't imagine the use for 10 identical software only having different icon. But you can surely replace `tool.ico` with new icon before build.

Comment: @Sinatr so how can i replace exacly this tool.ico?

Comment: Did you look at the link I provided, Adam? You can pass a flag to MSBuild...

Comment: Yeah im watching it right now, but it gonna takes me a lot of times to understand msbuild.exe  , maybe you can try help me and write cmd of that

Comment: I think you just need `MSBuild MySolution.sln /target:publish /property:ApplicationIcon=companyA.ico /p:Configuration=Release`. (change Release/Debug as necessary).

Comment: Yeah, I just tested and that works (provided `companyA.ico` is in the project folder for the WinForms application).

Comment: So please post a answear of this question and make full path etc to works :) and gonna aprove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MSBuild to do this:

```
MSBuild MySolution.sln /target:publish /property:ApplicationIcon=companyA.ico /p:Configuration=Release
```

Note Configuration=Release - change this as needed.

Simply replace `MySolution.sln` with the name of your solution. The new icon should be within the *project* folder (assuming that is different to your solution folder).

- The easy way to use MSBuild is to use the Developer Command Prompt (under Visual Studio 2017 in the Start menu).
- The other way is to manually locate it under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\bin` - note that you might have to replace 2017, Community, and 15.0 depending on the version that you're using. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44567280/where-is-msbuild-exe-installed-in-windows-when-installed-using-buildtools-full-e) for alternatives.

Comment: ok , thats replace ico of the main application , but how can i do the same think and replace .ico in example : Form1.cs , is it possbile to do that with MSBuild.exe?

Comment: Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203456/how-can-i-get-the-icon-from-the-executable-file-only-having-an-instance-of-its), you could add `this.Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);` in the form's constructor.  Otherwise, you need to set the icon from a resources file, and prepare it with the correct icon, I believe.