# How to create two setup with same form?

Tags: c#, winforms

My question is that, I have a winform application and I publish it  and installed my PC.

But I want to publish one more from that project and I want to install it too. but if I do that, it wants to update it. I dont want to update. I want to install two of them.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to publish multiple versions of the same ClickOnce application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750025/what-is-the-best-way-to-publish-multiple-versions-of-the-same-clickonce-applicat)

Comment: No need to install twice.  Once you install application you can put the exe file in any folder and make multiple copies provided and files (like dll) that are in the project bin folder are put in same folder as the exe.

Comment: @jdweng, installer takes care of creating and configuring environment. Only copy files might be not enough.

Comment: It is enough.  Do it all the time.  The install updates the windows dll if required.  Once the dll are updated the app can run from any place.  Doing right now on my project at work.

Comment: @jdweng actually I need to install jdweng. because I have a program installed but I saw that there are some problems in database. so I will use same program which is connected other database. I mean, i need to install second winform too. I changed sometings in winform as well

Comment: You only have to install once to config Windows to run application.  Once installed if the executable (any any reference files) are put in the correct relative locations you do not have to install again.  I often have to edit the ,csproj file to change full pathnames to relative path names.  I like making backups of my projects and using full pathnames the backups are using same paths as my latest code.  So I edit the csproj to allow me to copy projects so I have backups.