# Get nuget package version included in csproj in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2019, projects-and-solutions

In plain words I want to be able to modify .csproj files programmatically.

I am developing an application that replaces a nuget package with its actual project reference. This is application is used for debugging purpose. We have a huge set of packages that we add in our solution file. To do that I read a csproj file and apply a regex to find the specifies nuget package reference and add a project reference instead. This part was working, but its not picking the packages anymore.

The above can be done using the `dotnet` command but using that I cannot replace the old version back.

Is there any Microsoft nuget package available which can read the package references in csproj files?

Similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887538/modify-csproj-files-programmatically)  but Build.Engine is not available in the latest version.

Comment: There are some unclear points here, why do you need to do it, which packages format are you using, and how does your code look like

Comment: I am using a regex to find a package and its version
`PackageReference Include=\" packageName ".*Version=\""(\S*)""`

Comment: Using the above regex I search for package reference and replace it with the following string `<ProjectReference Include=\"{packageProjectPath}\" />`
It is replacing the package with project reference

Comment: I am working on another project at the moment. In a day or two I'll be back on this and will verify. Thanks for the solution you provided. :)

Comment: I have used these packages and able to retrieve packages references. 
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core
Microsoft.Build

Comment: Sure once I move back to the project I will work on the solution you provided. I will accept the answer once I test it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any Microsoft nuget package available which can read the
>   package references in csproj files?

**As far as I know**, [Microsoft.Build.Engine](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Engine/16.5.0?_src=template) does not support editing New Sdk format projects(**Net Core**) and is not compatible with this nuget package. This nuget package is just for old sdk format projects(**Net Framework**) and you cannot edit xml elements of **Net Core** Projects.

> Get nuget package version included in csproj in .Net Core 3.1

**Since** you want to get Nuget package References and their versions, you could try this function programmatically:

```
public class PackageReference
        {
            public string Include { get; set; } //get the nuget reference name
            public Version Version { get; set; } // get thee nuget package version
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

    //load the xxx.csproj file
            var doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx.csproj");
            var packageReferences = doc.XPathSelectElements("//PackageReference")
                .Select(pr => new PackageReference
                {
                    Include = pr.Attribute("Include").Value,
                    Version = new Version(pr.Attribute("Version").Value)
                });

            Console.WriteLine($"Project file contains {packageReferences.Count()} package references:");
            foreach (var packageReference in packageReferences)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{packageReference.Include}, version {packageReference.Version}");
            }


        }
```

**Update 1**

Just install [Microsoft.Build](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build/16.5.0?_src=template) and [Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core/16.5.0?_src=template) in a net framework project and then type these which can set a property in `xxx.csproj` file as `Build.Engine` nuget package did.

**Note** that it should be written in net framework projects rather than net core or net standard projects(which will cause errors).

```
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;
.......
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var collection = new ProjectCollection();
            var project = collection.LoadProject(@"xx:\xxx\xxx\xxx.csproj");
            project.SetProperty("Test","true");

            project.Save(@"xx:\xxx\xxx\xxx.csproj");


        }
    }
}
```

Hope it could help you.

Comment: can you also put as a side note that Microsoft.Build.Evaluation is incompatible with .netstandard. I have just encountered this issue and your first solution would be the applicable one if one uses .netstandard2.0.